# Variable is treated as uninitialized

Tags: c, variables, initialization

In the C code below (that is inspired by an example in K&R), the variable `nw` is treated as uninitialized:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define IN 1
#define OUT 0
main(){

    int c,nl,nw,nc = 0;
    int state = OUT;
    while((c=getchar())!=EOF){
        ++nc;
        if(c=='\n')
            ++nl;
        if(c==' ' || c=='\n' || c=='\t')
            state = OUT;
        else if(state == OUT){
            state = IN;
            ++nw;
        }
    }

    printf( "%d %d %d\n" , nl, nw, nc);
}
```

For example:

```
input: one two three
output: 1 796411731 14
```

The middle figure should have been 3 (`nw` = number of words)

I don't understand why this happens, given that I explicitly assign a value to it in the beginning.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> I don't understand why this happens, given that I explicitly assign a value to it in the beginning.

You do not assign the value to `nw`: `nc` is the only one assigned.

Unlike array initialization, where you could assign zeros to multiple elements by omitting them from the initializer, scalar variables must all be initialized separately:

```
int c, nl = 0, nw = 0, nc = 0;
```

Note that you do not need to initialize `c`, because it is assigned unconditionally in the loop header.

Answer (score 2):

This line:

```
int c,nl,nw,nc = 0;
```

Doesn't do what you think it does.  Only `nc` is set to 0.

If you want to initialize the others as well, you have to do so explicitly:

```
int c = 0, nl = 0, nw = 0, nc = 0;
```